# I am just confused in how the forin loop in js is used and why do we use const keyword in it

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

I have a object named user where one of the properties is skills and im trying to find a user who have the maximum no. of skills.

```
let maximum = 0;
let name;
for (const user in users) {
    const len = users[user].skills.length;
    if (len > maximum) {
        maximum = len;
        name = user;
    }
    console.log(maximum, user);
}
console.log(maximum, name);
OUTPUT:
3 'Alex'
8 'Asab'
8 'Brook'
8 'Daniel'
8 'John'
8 'Thomas'
8 'Paul'
8 'Asab'
```

My doubt is why do we use const keyword beside user in the third line. I have tried using this loop without specifying any data type the output is:

```
let maximum = 0;
let name;
for(user in users){
    const len = users[user].skills.length;
    if(len > maximum) {
        maximum = len;
        name = user;
    }
    console.log(maximum,user);
}
console.log(maximum,user);
OUTPUT:
3 'Alex'
8 'Asab'
8 'Brook'
8 'Daniel'
8 'John'
8 'Thomas'
8 'Paul'
8 'Paul'
```

when i don't use any data type i don't know why but it is changing the name variable on its own.

Comment: your last `console.log(maximum, user)` shouldn't it be `console.log(maximum, name)`?

Comment: also, could you please include your `users` object structure? I tried to imagine this, but can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/wnxm0423/ If I try to `console.log(user)` of course it will raise error `user is not defined`

Comment: the above happens if I use `for (const user in users)`, if using global `for (user in users)` then `user` is actually defined and contains the name of the last user. I don't know why, but `user` becomes accessible outside the for...in loop, which I do not understand (maybe I don't understand globals....).

Answer (score 1):

> My doubt is why do we use const keyword beside user in the third line.

Implicit globals [have problems](https://harshankur.hashnode.dev/the-curious-case-of-undeclared-global-variables-in-javascript), so its a very bad idea to not use *any* declaration keyword.

The value of `user` never changes (note that its a new `user` each time you go around the loop, not a reassignment to the existing one), so it is natural to declare it as a `const`.